# Path generator not working as expected/intended

Tags: c#

As you can see from the screenshot there are occasions when errors happen [image: errors]
My code should at those moments be observing the points above the white blocks, checking either side of them to see if there are any other empty sections, and if not the circled areas should be empty, not blocks.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //initiate lists (1 list for object), (2 list for occupied nearby)
        int[] list1 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list2 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list3 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list4 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list5 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list6 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list7 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list8 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list9 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list10 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list11 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list12 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list13 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list14 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list15 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list16 = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[][] lists = new int[][] { list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8, list9, list10, list11, list12, list13, list14, list15, list16 };

        int[] list1a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list2a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list3a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list4a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list5a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list6a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list7a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list8a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list9a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list10a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list11a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list12a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list13a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list14a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list15a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] list16a = new int[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[][] listsa = new int[][] { list1a, list2a, list3a, list4a, list5a, list6a, list7a, list8a, list9a, list10a, list11a, list12a, list13a, list14a, list15a, list16a };

        //assign walls
        Random random = new Random();
        //full
        // open = 2, unnasigned = 0, block = 1
        for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 15; j++)
            {
                // % chance of block spawning
                int r = 2;
                int p = random.Next(1, 11);
                if (p > 5) { r = 1; }
                else if (p < 6) { r = 2; }
                //do we have any surrounding open* blocks? (above,sides) *(not unassigned, OPEN)
                int[] openspaces = new int[3] { 0, 0, 0 }; //for recording which spaces are open
                var open = "no"; //assumed to be no
                //check space to sides and above, but not below as always unassigned
                try { if (lists[j][i - 1] == 2) { open = "yes"; openspaces[0] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }  //above
                try { if (lists[j + 1][i] == 2) { open = "yes"; openspaces[1] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }  //right
                try { if (lists[j - 1][i] == 2) { open = "yes"; openspaces[2] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }  //left
                if (open == "no")
                {
                    lists[j][i] = r; //  50/50 chance as completely singular square
                }
                else if (open == "yes")
                {   // if the spaces are open, do they have any other open or undecided blocks near them (under, sides)
                    int[] otheropen = new int[3] { 0, 0, 0 }; //for recording which nearby open block have other nearby open spaces
                    if (openspaces[0] == 1) //above
                    {
                        //check space to sides, but not above as not relavent, and below would be checking itself, and none are invalid
                        try { if ((lists[j + 1][i - 1] == 0 || lists[j + 1][i - 1] == 2) && listsa[j + 1][i - 1] != 1)  { otheropen[0] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
                        try { if ((lists[j - 1][i - 1] == 0 || lists[j - 1][i - 1] == 2) && listsa[j - 1][i - 1] != 1) { otheropen[0] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
                    }
                    else if (openspaces[0] == 0) { otheropen[0] = 2; } // if the block is not open it is ignored

                    if (openspaces[1] == 1) //right
                    {
                        //check space to right and below, but not above as not relavent, and left would be checking itself, and none are invalid
                        try { if ((lists[j + 1][i + 1] == 0 || lists[j][i - 1] == 2) && listsa[j + 1][i + 1] != 1) { otheropen[1] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
                        try { if ((lists[j + 2][i] == 0 || lists[j + 1][i] == 2) && listsa[j + 2][i] != 1) { otheropen[1] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
                    }
                    else if (openspaces[1] == 0) { otheropen[1] = 2; } // if the block is not open it is ignored

                    if (openspaces[2] == 1) //left
                    {
                        //check space to left and below, but not above as not relavent, and right would be checking itself, and none are invalid
                        try { if ((lists[j - 1][i + 1] == 0 || lists[j][i - 1] == 2) && listsa[j - 1][i + 1] != 1) { otheropen[2] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
                        try { if ((lists[j - 2][i] == 0 || lists[j - 1][i] == 2) && listsa[j - 2][i] != 1) { otheropen[2] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
                    }
                    else if (openspaces[2] == 0) { otheropen[2] = 2; } // if the block is not open it is ignored

                    if (otheropen[0] == 0 || otheropen[1] == 0 || otheropen[2] == 0) { lists[j][i] = 2; } //sets self as open, as a nearby open block has no other open blocks
                    else if (otheropen[0] != 0 && otheropen[1] != 0 && otheropen[2] != 0)
                            //yes all the near open block have a possible other route
                        {
                        lists[j][i] = r; // 50/50 as this block will not create a dead end
                        if (r == 1)//if original block closed then nearby open blocks will become invalid for next check, i.e. considered closed
                            {
                            try { if (otheropen[0] == 1) { listsa[j][i - 1] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }//top
                            try { if (otheropen[1] == 1) { listsa[j + 1][i] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }//right
                            try { if (otheropen[2] == 1) { listsa[j + 1][i] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }//left
                        } 
                        }
                }

            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= 15; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                if (lists[j][i] == 1) { Console.Write("██"); }
                if (lists[j][i] == 2) { Console.Write("░░"); }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I can't figure out why this error is happening, could it be due to the try checking. I know this is a large code dump, and probably pretty difficult to interpret from what I've posted, and I'm sure I could do stuff more efficiently as I'm new to C#, but any help would be incredible.

I really want for every square to be either accessible or to be a wall, but as you can see wall cross the whole area at points.

EDIT: Process explination:

So it iterates through a large array. First, it looks to see if there are any "open blocks" (of value 2) above and to the sides of the current specific value in the 2d array. If there aren't it randomly decides if the block is "open" or "filled" (value of 2 or 1 respectively).

If there is an open block, it will check each of those blocks surrounding blocks (the side and below) to see if there are any other open(2) blocks that could act as paths. If there are then it acknowledges this and randomly chooses again. If one of these blocks has no surrounding open blocks, then the current value should become an open block.

If a random choice is to be a 'filled' block after the latter process, then it will assign the near block as no longer being valid as open to the same process again, so that when another block is considering if it can use that as a path it knows it cannot.

Comment: Welcome.  Could you explain how the algorithm works a little more?  Wishing you well

Comment: No problem and thanks.  I have added your description into your question.   Hmmm not sure why the error sadly.

Comment: Your code is so hard to read it's hard to focus. I don't say that as an insult, I just think you might have better luck finding help if you fix it a little. Maybe you'll find the problem yourself by doing so. For example: 1- Use booleans, not strings with "yes"/"no" (bool isOpen = false;). 2- Use a 2 dimension array of int instead of an array of arrays (int[,] lists = new int[height, width];) 3- To investigate your bug, remove the randomness by using a seed in your random. (Random random = new Random(3);) 4- You should consider generating the "raw" map in a pass, then fixing it in a 2nd one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after reformatting your code to make it much easier I found what I believe to be the error (at least I cannot get the error to reproduce after these changes. (The code below is not reformatted to make it easier for you to find in your code)

In this section

```
if (openspaces[1] == 1) //right       
    {
    //check space to right and below, but not above as not relavent, and left would be checking itself, and none are invalid
    try { if ((lists[j + 1][i + 1] == 0 || lists[j][i - 1] == 2) && listsa[j + 1][i + 1] != 1) { otheropen[1] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
    try { if ((lists[j + 2][i] == 0 || lists[j + 1][i] == 2) && listsa[j + 2][i] != 1) { otheropen[1] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
}
else if (openspaces[1] == 0) { otheropen[1] = 2; } // if the block is not open it is ignored

if (openspaces[2] == 1) //left
{
    //check space to left and below, but not above as not relavent, and right would be checking itself, and none are invalid
    try { if ((lists[j - 1][i + 1] == 0 || lists[j][i - 1] == 2) && listsa[j - 1][i + 1] != 1) { otheropen[2] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
    try { if ((lists[j - 2][i] == 0 || lists[j - 1][i] == 2) && listsa[j - 2][i] != 1) { otheropen[2] = 1; } } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
}
```

If you look at where it says `try { if ...` you will notice that the second condition in your or statement is different then the first condition. They should be the same. It looks like you fell victim to a copy paste error.

As @Tipx suggested reformatting your code would have made this much easier to find. As you are new to C#, learn from the beginning to make your code readable. You will thank yourself later.

Note, your code still allows chunks of path to be separated from the main path (set your random seed to 0 and look at the top right corner), but you shouldn't have any more individual squares like you were having.

Comment: This with @Tipx 's tips were fantastically helpful, and I've made some appropriate changes, though I plan to do more formatting of my code to make it easier to read. Now I just need to figure how the separated paths takes place.

Comment: @GregoryHallam the separated paths happen because you only check 2-ish spaces away to see if a path potentially exists. There are times (random seed 0 for example), when that is not enough. If you want to *guarantee* that a path always exists, you will probably have to trace each square back to the beginning to make sure you can. Note - you could do that with something like the A* algorithm fairly easily if it was really a requirement.

Comment: But @Michael Sharp going through the process of elimination, what I intend to happen vs what happens is not correct, my theoretical function should still work? The example at seed 0, the error occurs at 4th row, 15th column. 
At this point the process should go like this:
Are there any free spaces above, left, right? Yes there's one above.
Does the one above have any spaces next to it? Right - No (No under special condition of being excluded, notified by second array), Left - No blocked, so the original should then be an open value.

Comment: @GregoryHallam with the if statement changes I pointed out that specific example is fixed. After that though, you still have the possibility of having sections that are not connected. Your Theoretical function works **most** of the time, but is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: So when you make those changes do observe at seed 0 there is still a gap of 7 open spaces in the top right corner? @MichaelSharp

Comment: Yep, and that's because you are only checking 2 spaces away to see if there is a potential path. So the wall gets created because 2 spaces away from it there is still open space, so it thinks there is potentially a path. You would have to check more then 2 spaces away to prevent that. Either with an algorithm like A*, or doing something like @Tipx suggested and doing a second pass through to fix it.

Comment: I see your reasoning, but that space should not be considered an open space, let me explain why: On the previous square, when the block is assigned to 1 (wall/blocked) it should assign the square above and to the sides as 1 in the array lista. This means when they are checked as being open(2), when checking the values next to the value above the next value (i hope that's not too confusing) they should be considered closed due to this code: listsa[j +x][i + x] != 1. The value IS equal to 1, so then otheropen[] becomes 0, and so the next value should be assigned to 2

Comment: Well after a long while and many mistakes, I learnt the uses of f5 f11 and run to cursor, and I managed to solve all the problems. I see what you mean about there being added alterations necessary. I've added one to remove vertical partitions, and one to remove looped partitions. Thanks for all the help @Michael Sharp

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help and that you got it all figured out.